# Keras: Overfitting Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am trying to create a binary image classification model using the malaria dataset from NIH (National Library of Medicine) which contains approximately 27,000 images of each class (infected/uninfected).

There seems to be overfitting and I have tried to play around with different batch sizes, steps per epoch/validation steps, using different hidden layers and adding callbacks etc. The graph always shows a straight line that is either dramatically increasing or decreasing, rather than increasing steadily with some decreases as it learns (which from my understanding, is how it should be). Below is an example, most turn out somewhat similar to this.

[image: Example plot]

I'm new to deep learning, I have read a lot about overfitting and trying to find a solution. But I think there must be something I'm doing wrong and/or misunderstanding. If someone is able to spot something that doesn't look right and is able to point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import constants as c
import numpy as np
import keras

# Clear session and instantiate model
keras.backend.clear_session()
model = Sequential()

# Load images & labels
cells = np.load(c.cells_path)
labels = np.load(c.labels_path)

# Shuffle the entire dataset
n = np.arange(cells.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(n)

# Update numpy files with shuffled data
cells = cells[n]
labels = labels[n]

# Split the dataset into train/validation/test
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(cells, labels, test_size=1 - c.train_ratio, shuffle=False)
val_x, test_x, val_y, test_y = train_test_split(test_x, test_y, test_size=c.test_ratio / (c.test_ratio + c.val_ratio),
                                                shuffle=False)

# The amount of images in each set
print('Training data shape: ', train_x.shape)
print('Validation data shape: ', val_x.shape)
print('Testing data shape: ', test_x.shape)

# Neural network
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=c.input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Data augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                   rotation_range=20,
                                   width_shift_range=0.05,
                                   height_shift_range=0.05,
                                   shear_range=0.05,
                                   zoom_range=0.05,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
testing_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

training_dataset = train_datagen.flow(train_x, train_y, batch_size=32)
validation_dataset = validation_datagen.flow(val_x, val_y, batch_size=32)
testing_dataset = validation_datagen.flow(val_x, val_y, batch_size=32)

# Add callbacks to prevent overfitting
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy',
                   min_delta=0,
                   patience=2,
                   verbose=0,
                   mode='max')

rlrop = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                          factor=0.2,
                          patience=0.5,
                          min_lr=0.001)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("Model.h5")

# Perform backpropagation and update weights in model
history = model.fit_generator(training_dataset,
                              epochs=50,
                              validation_data=validation_dataset,
                              callbacks=[es, checkpoint, rlrop])

# Save model & weights
model.save_weights("Model_weights.h5")
model.save("Model.h5")

# Plot accuracy graph
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: how do you know its overfitting?, your validation accuracy > train accuracy from the graph

Comment: "The graph always shows a straight line that is either dramatically increasing or decreasing" The graphs shows four points for each line, since Keras only logs the accuracies at the **end** of each Epoch. From your validation loss, the model trains already in one epoch, there is no sign of overfitting (validation loss does not decrease). A bit odd that val loss is higher than train loss, but you have data augmentation that effectively makes the test dataset easier to classify, so I'd not worry too much

Comment: Yes. Your accuracy line plots look really good, as @GPhilo said, it even is kind of strange to have such a better val acc than train, but in any case this doesn't fit in the definition of overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be a case of overfitting. Without looking much at it, would do the following:

1. leave the filters at 32 in the fist layer and gradually double on every following convolutional layer.
2. Since the variations in the images aren't that significant lower the Dropout rate.

Oddly enough, this is something I built when I was first trying Tensorflow 2.0, you can check it [here](https://github.com/axegon/tf2_malaria_cell_detection/blob/master/malaria_ml/train.py#L53).

Comment: Ah, it seems I was misreading the graph. I was under the impression it was a case of overfitting because the accuracy would jump from roughly 80% to 90% after the second epoch.

The other thing is that the test results are quite poor! It means that it is not generalizing very well, and I thought that overfitting was to blame.

I have tried what you suggested and lowering the dropout seems to have made the training validation a little higher. But the testing results (unseen data) are still poor.

Comment: Overfitting is when your model learns the actual dateset and performs really well using that data but performs poorly on new data. I'd advise you to base your layers on something that's proven to work (i.e. vgg). On a second glance, Put the dropout layer before the dense layers. Use relu activation in your dense layer and adam optimizer when you compile the model(Adam is often a good starting point since it's less prone to converge in a local point). Play with the learning rate as well. Take a closer look at the example model I gave you and see if there's something you can lift from there.